# Медленная работа с интеренетом через wifi роутер

Tags: dns, wifi, роутер

С планшета внезапно стал медленно работать интернет.  Пинг показывает нормальный, а общее время считает огромное, порядка 10 секунд, traceroute тоже самое. С ПК всё нормально.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге дело было в днс, прописал гугловские днс в роутере (именно там, потому что я пробовал прописывать их в wifi соединении - не помогло) и теперь всё летает.

Comment: Вы когда DNS меняли - роутер перезагрузился, возможно это и помогло, роутеры часто так тупят. Хотя может конечно вы правы и кривой был dns. правда dns ни как не влияет на время пинга, только на время определения ip по имени.

Comment: @Mike но первое дело при ping ya.ru - это как раз ya.ru разрезолвить.